# How to test function that passed as an value for key of arguments object?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest

I have export like that

```
export default someModule.method({
  key: (arg1, arg2) => {
    return {
      'smth': arg1.method,
      'smth2': arg2.method
    }
  }
})
```

and jest indicates that the 3rd line (with return) should be tested
so how is it gonna be?

Comment: From what you've posted, we've no idea. What does `someModule.method` _do_ with it? _Does_ it ever call the `key`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe this file is actually expressWinston logger and it is used as middleware